# Vim hard or soft tab depending on what's used in the file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there a vim command or plugin that will span the source file I'm opening, and adjust my tab setting to whatever is used in the file.

I currently work on a diverse codebase at work, with some source files using hard tabs, other 4 space soft tabs, and other's 2 space soft tabs. My hard tab, if I forgot to changes, can lead to ugly whitespace in different editors if I forget to change it when I'm editting a soft tab file.

I'd like to not have to remember to check whatever's convention is used in a file every time I open a buffer, and adjust my preferences accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I use [yaifa](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3096) with great success. It's pretty much an "install-and-forget" plugin that does what it says it does without ever getting in the way. Working in the messy environment I work in was horrible until I found that gem.

Answer (score 0):

If most people at work use Vim (and/or Emacs), you can encode the indent settings within the file itself, see `:help modeline` (at least Emacs has something similar). Of course, agreeing on a common setting and gradually migrating to it would be even better :-)

In case you can't do that or things are just too chaotic, you need a plugin to dynamically adapt the indent settings. My [IndentConsistencyCop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690) checks whether the buffer's indentation is consistent and conforms to tab settings, and then offers to adapt the settings to the detected ones. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following function (found it somewhere on the web) with good success. Just put it into your `.vimrc`:

```
function Kees_settabs()
    if len(filter(getbufline(winbufnr(0), 1, "$"), 'v:val =~ "^\\t"')) > len(filter(getbufline(winbufnr(0), 1, "$"), 'v:val =~ "^ "'))
        set noet
    else
        set et
    endif
endfunction
autocmd BufReadPost * call Kees_settabs()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth) by the prolific Tim Pope:

> This plugin automatically adjusts 'shiftwidth' and 'expandtab' heuristically based on the current file, or, in the case the current file is new, blank, or otherwise insufficient, by looking at other files of the same type in the current and parent directories. In lieu of adjusting 'softtabstop', 'smarttab' is enabled.
>
> I wrote this because I wanted something fully automatic. My goal is that by installing this plugin, you can remove all indenting related configuration from your vimrc.
>
> If your file is consistently indented with hard tabs, 'shiftwidth' will be set to your 'tabstop'. Otherwise, a 'tabstop' of 8 is enforced.